# Installing Dexy looked ok, but Dexy does not work

Tags: linux, debian, python

I just tried to install Dexy on a Debian 4.7 server.
Python was installed but not pip, so I did some research and found how to do it :

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
(...)
$ sudo easy_install pip
(...)
```

All these steps went fine, so I could start installing dexy :

```
$ sudo pip install dexy
(...)
==========================================================================
WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
Plain-Python installation succeeded.
==========================================================================
Running setup.py install for web.py

Successfully installed dexy pexpect BeautifulSoup4 PyYAML cashew chardet inflection jinja2 ply pygments python-modargs requests dexy-viewer Markdown docutils markupsafe web.py
Cleaning up...
```

Ok, apart from the "C extension" warning, it looked fine (I'm not a Python specialist, but the "Successfully installed dexy" message made me optimist)

However, when I launch dexy, I have fatal errors :

```
$ dexy setup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dexy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: requests>=0.10.6
```

I did a little reseach on the net about this, but couldn't find anything. What can I do ?

(side note : I do have many reputation (4000+) on Stackoverflow site, but not on superuser, so I can't create the new 'Dexy' tag right now. Am I on the correct site to post this question ?)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I just found a way !

I just installed (again) dexy directly with easy_install

```
$ sudo easy_install dexy
Searching for dexy
Best match: dexy 1.0.14
Adding dexy 1.0.14 to easy-install.pth file
Installing dexy script to /usr/local/bin
(...)
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chardet-2.2.1-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for dexy
```

And now, it's looking good !

```
$ dexy setup
$ dexy
didn't find any document config files (like dexy-env.json dexy.txt dexy.yaml)
dexy run finished in 0.093
dexy reports finished in 0.109
```

I hope it won't be messy to have it installed both ways... :/